# SQL Server ON DELETE trigger not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger in my database.

I have two tables, one for customer information and one for customer orders.
I want to create a `FOR DELETE` trigger so when I delete an order from the order table, the cost of that order should be reduced from the customer's account.

First I create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, it works well!

Here is the code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[set_customer_debt]
ON [dbo].[orders]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE customer
    SET debt = debt + (SELECT cost FROM orders
                       INNER JOIN services ON services.service# = orders.service#
                       WHERE orders.order# IN (SELECT order# FROM inserted))
    WHERE customer# IN (SELECT customer# FROM inserted)
END
```

Then I copied this and change it to FOR DELETE, but it just return NULL for debt:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[delete_customer_debt]
ON [dbo].[orders]
FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE customer
    SET debt = debt - (SELECT cost FROM orders
                       INNER JOIN services ON services.service# = orders.service#
                       WHERE orders.order# IN (SELECT order# FROM deleted))
    WHERE customer# IN (SELECT customer# FROM deleted)
END
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'd avoid this idea all together; any time you want to know the balance of a customer account, add up the orders using a grouping query

Comment: It's a **customer** - not a "costumer" ......